# Removing double quotes before bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm trying to load a file using bulk insert, but data isn't inserted correctly because some of the data is covered by quotation marks.

I've tried using a format file, but it doesn't work becasue not ALL the rows in that column contain quotes. Only some do. e.g.

```
columna
abc
cdf
"dfd"
dfs
"aee"
```

So my format file doesn't work.

My bulk insert code:

```
bulk insert tablename
from 'C:/...'
 with 
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,  
    rowterminator = '0x0a' 
    ,formatfile = 'file.fmt'
     )
```

Format file:

```
10.0
5
1       SQLCHAR             0       1000      ","       1      "a"                           ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       1000      ",\""       2     "b"                 ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       1000      "\",\""       3      "d" <- has quotes  ""                              
4       SQLCHAR             0       1000      ",\""     4      "e"                          ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       1000      "\n"   5      "f"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you bulk insert?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu edited the post.

Comment: What does your format file look like?

Comment: if the bulk insert works fine accepting the double quotes.. what you can do is a bit of housekeeping... update the column data by using `replace` function

Comment: @maSTAShuFu i cant do that because the column gets split into 2 columns, as some of the data might contain commas.

Comment: how many columns are you talking about?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu only 1 column has quotes, and when inserted, that column splits into 2. i have more columns in that file tho, which have no quotes

Comment: exactly my point.. after the bulk insert... update the columns to remove the double quotes.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu then how do i get the data back into 1 columns instead of 2?

Comment: He means to remove them after they're in the table already.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other way to remove double quotes in the column/s then what you can do is to do a post process where you update the affected column/s with `replace`

ie.

```
update mytable set col1 = replace(col1,'"',''),col2 = replace(col2,'"','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem with some data which also had some quotation marks inside the data so I couldn't use replace. Just in case there is this:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
ColumnA VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES  ('abc')
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES  ('cdf')
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES  ('"dfd"')
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES  ('dfs')
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES  ('"aee"')
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES  (' efg ')
GO

SELECT * FROM SomeTable
GO

--TRIM THE DATA

UPDATE SomeTable SET ColumnA =LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnA))
GO

--DELETE THE DELIMITERS

UPDATE SomeTable SET ColumnA = LEFT(ColumnA,LEN(ColumnA)-1) WHERE RIGHT(ColumnA,1) LIKE '"'
GO
UPDATE SomeTable SET ColumnA = RIGHT(ColumnA,LEN(ColumnA)-1) WHERE LEFT(ColumnA,1) LIKE '"'
GO

--RETRIM THE DATA

UPDATE SomeTable SET ColumnA =LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnA))
GO

SELECT * FROM SomeTable
GO
```